# fstream fails to write/open files on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi3, fstream

I am trying to run a cpp program on raspberry pi 3 b+ (from 'pi' user) but when I try to open a file with 'fstream' library it doesn't work.
I am using the following code (from main):

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
std::string path = "/NbData";
std::ofstream nbData(path);
if (!nbData) {
    std::cout << "Error during process...";
    return 0;
}
nbData.seekp(std::ios::beg);
```

The program always fails there and stops because no file is created (I don't get a fatal error but the test fails and it outputs 'Error during process' which means no file was created).
I am compiling with the following command (there are no issues when I compile):

```
g++ -std=c++0x nbFinder.cpp -o nbFinder
```

I have already tried my program on Xcode and everything worked perfectly...

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? Can you create a file in that directory using "touch", for example? (i.e. without your code, just with your normal permissions)

Comment: Yes I can because I am using 'pi' that has all permissions

Comment: passing path.c_str() doesn't work

Comment: @Ian, since c++11 there is a constructor taking a std::string.

Comment: @Seth, are you sure that pi has all permissions? Usual set up is to use a user without all the permissions and acquires them only when needed using `sudo`.

Comment: When I use sudo to execute my program, everything seems to be working but in fact nothing is written in the file. I mean the program is running but when I stop it to watch what was written in the file, nothing appears. Do I have to save the file or something like that before ending the program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your path. You must put the file, you are using just the path and if the path do not exist will throw an error. In your case you just using `std::string path = "/NbData";`, that is you path not your file.
To be able to open your file you need make sure your path exist. Try use the code bellow, he will check if the path exist case not will create and then try to open your file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main() {

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::string path = "./test_dir/";
    std::string file = "test.txt";

    // Will check if thie file exist, if not will creat
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(path.c_str(), &info) != 0) {
        std::cout << "cannot access " << path << std::endl;
        system(("mkdir " + path).c_str());
    } else if(info.st_mode & S_IFDIR) {
        std::cout << "is a directory" << path << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "is no directory" << path << std::endl;
        system(("mkdir " + path).c_str());
    }

    std::ofstream nbData(path + file);
    if (!nbData) {
        std::cout << "Error during process...";
        return 0;
    }
    nbData.seekp(std::ios::beg);

    return 0;
}
```